# UITextFieldViewMode.UnlessEditing error

Tags: swift

Morning,

I have one form with 3 UItextFields. I want to display rightView (error image) in my differents textfield with UITextFieldViewMode.UnlessEditing but I have a memory problem.

@IBAction func nextRegisterStep(){

```
    self.showErrorsImage();


}

func showErrorsImage(){

    if pseudoField.text.isEmpty {
        self.displayRightView(pseudoField)
    }

    if !Validation.isValidEmail(emailField.text) {
        self.displayRightView(emailField)
    }

    if !Validation.isValidPassword(passwordField.text){
        self.displayRightView(passwordField)
    }


}

func displayRightView(sender : AnyObject){

    if sender.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
        (sender as! UITextField).rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.UnlessEditing
    }

}
```

can you help me?
thanks

Comment: You have to give more details if you want anyone to help you troubleshoot the problem. What is the problem? How do you know? Does your app crash? Where?

Comment: Before  call my function nextRegisterStep(). the memory consumption is 24Mo after exceeded  200 MB

Comment: There is nothing in your code that indicates memory leaks. It must be in your Validation class or related code.